# Notification for keyboard

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a variable 'balance' which I'm initializing to '0' onClick of a button which calls my custom adapter 'MyAdpater'. I've an EditText in my activity. When I hide/show the keyboard, I don't get notified about it. I've vainly tried configChnage Method already.

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Toast.makeText(Ledger.this, "Config Change has been called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Checks whether a hardware or on-screen keyboard is available
    balance = 0;
        ourCursor = db.getLedger(et.getText().toString(), from.getText()
                .toString(), to.getText().toString());

        id.clear();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(Ledger.this, ourCursor, false);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

(This method isn't called when keyboard (dis)appears because the Toast doesn't appear.)

This is my code

```
class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        balance = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB3);
        TextView tv4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB4);
        TextView tv5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB5);
        String date = c.getString(1);
        tv1.setText(date.substring(6, 8) + "/" + date.substring(4, 6) + "/"
                + date.substring(0, 4));
        tv2.setText("" + c.getDouble(3));
        tv3.setText("" + c.getDouble(4));
        balance = balance + c.getDouble(4) - c.getDouble(3);
        tv4.setText("" + (balance));
        tv5.setText((c.getDouble(3) > c.getDouble(4) ? "CR." : "DR."));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.text_view_for_list_view_account_balance, parent,
                false);
    }
}
```

It doesn't initialize the value of my variable 'balance = 0' as I show/hide the keyboard & therefore, the value of balance just keeps on increasing every time I show/hide the keyboard. I want to set balance = 0 whenever I show/hide the keyboard. Is there any method to do this?

Please help. Thanks. :)

Comment: Adding this data in BindAdapter won't work as it'll always increase my variable 'balance' every time I scroll through the adapter.

Comment: Why and when are you incrementing `balance`?

Comment: @Sam: c.getDouble(4) - c.getDouble(3) != 1

Comment: This is the second blunder I've made in a row, my head must be somewhere else...

Comment: :)
But my question is.. why is newView() getting called when the keyboard appears & disappears?
Because according to definition newView() is called only when the layout is inflated for the first time. Isn't it?

Comment: It is possible the whole layout is scrapped and rebuilt when the keyboard opens and closes. Any View that was partially covered by the keyboard will definitely be redrawn.

Comment: Oh! Is there any way I can stop that? :o
Please give me some code to stop it. That'd be really great. I won't have to change anything at all then. Thanks. :)

Comment: You can tell the device that you want to handle [configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). I have never tried what you want to do, so I don't know for certain how this will work...

Answer (score 0):

In [World of ListView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) (or [TurboCharge Your UI](https://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html)) Android's Romain Guy states that you cannot rely on the Adapter's build order. It may build top-down, bottom-up, or start somewhere in the middle and travel in either direction; this design choice relates to efficiency.

So you need to find a way to calculate `balance` that is not reliant on the build order...

---

Also your current Adapter does not support scrolling, since `newView()` is not called for every row in your database. The number of time `newView()` gets called in your ListView (or Spinner, etc) relates to how many rows fit on the user's screen.

Comment: Okay, Sam, thanks. So is there any way to calculate balance using CustomAdapter? I can do it using ArrayLists of different types & use a BaseAdapter but that'll lead to change in big chunk of code because I'm using this same logic in many classes. :/

Comment: I recommend sticking with a CursorAdapter, they are inherently more efficient than converting all of the data to an ArrayList. If the configuration changes above don't work you could add a new column to your database to track this data or loop through your Cursor in the Adapter's constructor to create an ArrayList of balances and use this in `newView()` with the data inside the Cursor.