# Notification for keyboard fires

Tags: android, android-keypad

Is there anyway to get a know when a keyboard (dis)appears?
Actually I'm trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525678/newview-in-cursoradapter/14525883#comment20255442_14525883)

I haven't found anything which answers my question. I think I wasn't clear enough.

This
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/nRaBoB8F54I 
is a pretty old thread but it explains my problem pretty well.

I was wondering if there's any solution available to this now.

Please help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, you can try it and let me know.  But if you put

```
android:configChange="keyboardHidden"
```

in your manifest for the activity, that will make it call `onConfigChange` of your activity passing it in a Configuration object where you can query the `keyboardHidden` member variable and see if its the same as it was last time or not.  Note you will also have to check `hardKeyboardHidden` to tell if it was a slideout keyboard that went away or the software keyboard.

The problem is I know this works for pulling out the hardware keyboard.  I don't know if it also calls you for displaying the software keyboard.  Worth a try though.

Comment: public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  
  Toast.makeText(Ledger.this, "Config Change has been called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Comment: The function onConfigurationChanged isn't even called when I show/hide the keyboard. (to check whether the above method works.. I tried to change the config from landscape to portrait & vice-versa & it worked). :/

Comment: Worth a shot, I'd only tried it to detect when a hardware keyboard was slid out before (that does work).  In that case I think the answer is still the same-  no, there's no reliable way to tell when a keybaord goes away.  And any hack around you use won't work with a keyboard that had a minimize button on it.

Comment: One other thought-  you can override onSizeChanged in your view.  That tells you when the size of a view changes.  THat would tell you when the keyboard goes away because you have more room.  It would also be called on initial display, rotation, and changing on screen items visibility.